# What algorithm does SDL2 use to draw line?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sdl, sdl-2

SDL2 provides a `SDL_RenderDrawLine` method to draw line. I wonder what algorithm does SDL2 use for this method, given there are a few algorithms for drawing lines.

Comment: SDL is open source, just check out the source.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do want to know ? (By the way, lines are universally drawn by Bresenham or antialiased Bresenham - what are the "few" others ?).

Comment: The implementation is probably inside some Renderer like OpenGL. In case of OpenGL, it may be that some interpolation is done between a pair of vertices. For example, see [this](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/373232d63fffdca74fffefab97c5e455576fbb91/src/render/opengl/SDL_render_gl.c#L892) function.